# How to prevent screen reader from reading src attribute from img tag in IE

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

I am facing a very straight forward problem with screen readers in IE9 or below. When the screen reader looks at an image tag, which has the `src` attribute, it reads the content of the `src`. Even if the `alt` attribute is present, it reads the contents inside the `src`.

To be perfectly clear: *this only happens in IE 9 or below*

Here is a very simple example of my code:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="some image"/>
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Any help on how to get around this issue or the fact that no, there is not solution **plus proof**, would be very appreciated.

Comment: Which screen reader is doing this?

Comment: NVDA right now, but its in my best interest that it works in all/most screen readers. It later occurred to me that it could be part of the screen reader's configurations to do this despite what you do in your HTML

Comment: Which version of NVDA and which browser and version?

Comment: Latest version, IE9 or below

Comment: sorry, I see now that IE9 and below is in the question :-) if NVDA is reading the src, then that means that the browser is exposing it. I would report the bug to Microsoft and move on. NVDA is the most standards compliant screen reader on Windows.

Comment: I was hoping that would be my last resort, if I could find a way around it via code that would be optimal, but alas if all fails then why not... thanks mate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're hitting a bug with a new verison of NVDA, and an old version of IE.

Try the code with Firefox (recent) and NVDA, or a version of JAWs from the IE9 era (version 12 I think would do), and I'm fairly sure you'll get the alt text.

In terms of proof, the official document for this is the WAI ARIA roles "[Text alternative computation](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#textalternativecomputation)", which then refers to the HTML4 "[How to specify alternative text](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.8)".

Basically, the alt text is what should be used, you're hitting a bug in a combination of screenreader and browsers that are very unlikely to be used together. (NVDA works best with Firefox, you would use Jaws with IE9.)

Comment: I can believe that NVDA + old version of IE is causing an uncaught bug on the screen reader, absolute proof of such is only possible when NVDA tells me so after I email them, but nevertheless thanks for looking into this. I'll accept your answer as being the most helpful so far

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using a 'title' attribute. A lot of times, 'title' is what is used for readers to get the description.

```
<img src=".." alt=".." title="some image" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I will try this in about 12 hours, hope you don't mind standing by.

Comment: Most current screenreaders don't announce the title by default, only after the user turns it on via a setting.

Comment: Did this happen to work? If not, do you mind sharing how you solved it?